# How to know if core has been already binded

Tags: binding, pthreads, mpi, cpu-cores

```
hwloc_obj_t obj = hwloc_get_obj_by_depth(topology, depth_CORE,MyRank%4);
hwloc_cpuset_t cpuset = hwloc_bitmap_dup(obj->cpuset);
hwloc_set_cpubind(topology, cpuset, 0)
```

Is there anyway in hwloc to know if a thread is already binded to that "cpuset". 
Reason why I need to know this:
Suppose I have a quad core. But if I issue 8 processors at runtime. So it happens to bind 2 process to each core. However I want to bind process to core only when it is free. So is there anyway I could know that core has been already binded to process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the only way to do so is to enumerate all processes and check whether some of them are bound to the specified core. You can get an idea how to do that by examining the source code of the [hwloc-ps](https://github.com/open-mpi/hwloc/blob/master/utils/hwloc-ps.c) utility. What it does is that it reads through the `/proc` filesystem and extracts process PIDs form there, then uses `hwloc_get_proc_cpubind()` to obtain the binding mask. This should work on Linux and Solaris, as well as *BSD systems with mounted `/proc`. On Windows one should use the system-specific API from the [Tool Help library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686837%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to obtain the list of PIDs. OS X does not support processor affinity.

Comment: Thanks!  I could get pid using getpid(). but when I use it  hwloc_get_proc_cpubind(topology,ppid[i],set[i],0) it gives segmentation fault. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Do you initialise `set[i]` using `hwloc_bitmap_alloc()`?

Comment: No i used "hwloc_cpuset_t set[Numprocs]" Is it wrong?

Comment: `hwloc_cpuset_t` (as well as `hwloc_bitmap_t`) is a pointer type. You should allocate each element of the array using `hwloc_bitmap_alloc()`.

Comment: for(i=0;i<Numprocs;i++) { if(i==MyRank) { ppid[MyRank]=getpid(); ppid2[i]=ppid[i]; } } Then when I use this ppid2 in hwloc_get_proc_cpubind(topology,ppid2[i],set[i],0) it takes ppid only for that MyRank and others are marked 0. Therefore while comparing set[i] and cpuset later, it never matches. How to correct this?

Comment: You should use `MPI_Allgather` to gather all PID values in each process. You should also make sure that you do not do that across nodes since the PID of a process on one node makes no sense on a different node. Also, why are you implementing that yourself? Can't you just use the built-in binding options of your MPI library? For example `--bind-to-core` in Open MPI and `-env I_MPI_PIN 1` for Intel MPI.

Comment: hwloc_obj_t obj = hwloc_get_obj_by_depth(topology, depth_PU, MyRank%12);
cpuset = hwloc_bitmap_dup(obj->cpuset);
hwloc_bitmap_singlify(cpuset);
hwloc_get_proc_cpubind(topology,ppid2[i],set[i],0);
for(i=0;i<Numprocs;i++){
if(cpuset==set[i])
bflag=1;                        }
                        if(bflag==0)
                                if (hwloc_set_cpubind(topology, cpuset, HWLOC_CPUBIND_THREAD))   if I enter more than 12 core it binds to few cores multiple times. that is bflag never turns 1. My reason of doing this to stop multiple bindings to same core.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestions. Could you please suggest what am I doing wrong while comparing cpuset and set[i].

Comment: You cannot compare CPU sets using `cpuset == set[i]`. Those are pointers to actual bitmap structures. Comparing pointers does not compare the content they point at. You should either use `hwloc_bitmap_intersects()` or `hwloc_bitmap_isequal()`.